# Login in douban.com with python display b''

Tags: python

I want to login 'douban.com' with python session

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.douban.com/'
logurl = 'https://accounts.douban.com/passport/login_popup'
data = {'username': 'abc@gmail.com',
        'password': 'abcdef'}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
            Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.87 Safari/537.36'}
se = requests.session()
request = se.post(logurl, data=data, headers=headers)
request1 = se.get(url)
print(request1.content)
```

this display "b''",I don't get this work or not!

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an empty response, meaning the request is not working properly. You want to debug the request further by looking into Your response. Check [Requests lib documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content). `request1.status_code` and `request1.headers` might interest you.

The `b''` is just a Bytes literal prefix. [Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals):

Comment: [HTTP 408](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/418)
The server is refusing your request